# How to add figure labels above Y axis in multi panel plot

Tags: r, plot, label

How can I add A), B), C), D) right above Y axis.

```
a <- seq(1, 29) + 4*runif(29, 0.4)
b <- seq(1, 29)^2 + runif(29, 0.98)

#Divide the screen in 2 columns and 2 lines
par(mfrow=c(2, 2))

#Add a plot in each sub-screen !
plot(a, b , pch=20)
plot(a - b , pch=18)
hist(a, border=FALSE, col=rgb(0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7), main="")
boxplot(a , col="grey" , xlab="a")
```

I tried some ways, like using `locator()` to find the coordinates and then use `text()`. they do not work well.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mtext`, `par()$usr` helps to get plotting region.

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(2, 2))  ## change pars

## panel A
plot(a, b , pch=20)
mtext('A)', side=3, at=par()$usr[1], line=1)

## panel B
plot(a - b , pch=18)
mtext('B)', side=3, at=par()$usr[1], line=1)

## panel C
hist(a, border=FALSE, col=rgb(0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7), main="")
mtext('C)', side=3, at=par()$usr[1], line=1)

## panel D
boxplot(a , col="grey" , xlab="a")
mtext('D)', side=3, at=par()$usr[1], line=1)

par(op)  ## reset pars
```

[image]